# AuthenticationResult AcquireToken method won't let me use the non async method

Tags: oauth, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am trying to get data from Dynamics CRM Online, but cannot even authenticate and get an access token. The problem is that I am not able to call the AcquireToken method in my console application.

Anyone know how to authenticate and get an access token ?

I am using the below tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/connect-customer-engagement-web-services-using-oauth

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Posting some code might help...

Comment: You're failing on this line `AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireToken(resource, clientId, new Uri(redirectUrl));`? Are you getting an exception?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use ADAL.Net v2 library and not v3.
The v3 library only supports the async method, whereas the v2 supports the non async method.